# Bootstrap multiple dropdown buttons not displaying properly

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have searched on the internet and even on this site for the answers but no luck. The problem I am having is the two dropdown button sign in and sign up are displaying both dropdown menu when there are clicked I used the btn-group class to fix this but then the problem arises it doesn't display properly on smaller mobile screens changing it to btn class fixes it just a bit then the issue is the options are displaying horizontally and not being stacked which looks awful. I also tried data-target but that isn't working either any help would be appreciated. Here is a sample of my html and css code.

**Code**

```css
.navbar {
  background-color: #00CED1;
  border: none;
}

.navbar-default .navbar-brand {
  color: white;
  font-family: Tahoma;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-style: italic;
}

.navbar-left {
  width: 70%;
  margin-left: -15px;
}

#navForm {
  border: none;
}

#loginbtn {
  margin-right: 16px;
  background: none;
  color: white;
  border: 2px solid white;
}

#searchbtn {
  margin-left: -13px;
  background-color: #00b3b3;
  color: white;
  border-color: #00b3b3;
}

#submitbtn {
  width: 100%;
}

#burgerbtn:hover {
  background-color: #1673b1;
}

#searchbtn:hover {
  background-color: #1673b1;
  border-color: #1673b1;
}

#search {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #00b3b3;
  border: none;
  color: white;
}

#password,
#username {
  margin-top: 15px;
}

b,
strong {
  color: #1673b1;
}

#form {
  border: none;
}

#navdiv {
  border: none;
}

#form2 input::placeholder {
  color: white;
}

#form input::placeholder {
  color: white;
}

.navbar-default .navbar-toggle .icon-bar {
  background-color: white;
}

.dropdown-menu {
  padding-left: 15px;
  padding-right: 15px;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 720px) {
  b,
  strong {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0.5%;
    left: 35%;
  }
  #navdiv {
    width: 80%;
  }
  .navbar-toggle {
    border: none;
  }
  #navdiv {
    width: 165%;
  }
  .navbar-left {
    width: 100%;
  }
  #loginbtn {
    margin-left: 5%;
  }
}

#navdiv1 {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <title>LearnLyte Connect Share Learn</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/bootstrap.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/app-bootstrap.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <div class="navbar-header">
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#"><strong><font color="white">LearnLyte</font></strong></a>
        <button id="burgerbtn" type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navForm">
                            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        </button>
      </div>
      <div id="navdiv" class="navbar-left navbar-form">
        <form id="form">
          <div class="form-group col-xs-6">
            <input id="search" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search Here...">
          </div>
          <button type="submit" id="searchbtn" class="btn btn-default">Search</button>
        </form>
      </div>
      <div class="navbar-right form-inline">
        <div class=" collapse navbar-collapse navbar-form" id="navForm">
          <!--<div>-->
          <button id="signupbtn" type="button" class="btn dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Sign Up</button>
          <div class="dropdown-menu">
            <div class="text-center">
              <h4><b> Sign Up</b></h4>
            </div><br>
            <form autocomplete="off">
              <div class="form-group">
                <label for="firstname">Firstname</label>
                <input type="text" id="firstname" tabindex="1" class="form-control" placeholder="Firstname">
              </div>
              <div class="form-group">
                <label for="lastname">Lastname</label>
                <input type="text" id="lastname" tabindex="2" class="form-control" placeholder="Lastname">
              </div>
              <div class="form-group">
                <label for="username">Username</label>
                <input type="text" tabindex="3" class="form-control" placeholder="Username">
              </div>
              <div class="form-group">
                <label for="email">Email</label>
                <input type="email" tabindex="4" class="form-control" placeholder="Email">
              </div>
            </form>
          </div>
          <!--</div>-->
          <!--<div>-->
          <button id="loginbtn" type="button" class="btn dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false"> Sign In</button>
          <div class="dropdown-menu">
            <div class="text-center">
              <h4><b> Sign In</b></h4>
            </div><br>
            <form autocomplete="off">
              <div class="form group">
                <label for="username">Username</label>
                <input type="text" id="username" tabindex="1" class="form-control" placeholder="Username" autocomplete="off">
              </div>
              <div class="form-group">
                <label for="password">Password</label>
                <input type="password" id="password" tabindex="2" class="form-control" placeholder="Password" autocomplete="off">
              </div>
              <br>
              <div class="form-group">
                <div class="text-center">
                  <a href="#" class="forgot-password">Forgot password?</a>
                </div>
              </div>
              <br><br>
              <div>
                <button id="submitbtn" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-block">Sign In</button>
              </div>
            </form>
          </div>
          <!--</div>-->
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </nav>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/bootstrap.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <title>LearnLyte Connect Share Learn</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <div class="navbar-header">
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#"><strong><font color="white">LearnLyte</font></strong></a>
        <button id="burgerbtn" type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navForm">
     <span class="icon-bar"></span>
     <span class="icon-bar"></span>
     <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    </button>
      </div>
      <div id="navdiv" class="navbar-left navbar-form">
        <form id="form">
          <div class="input-group">
            <input id="search" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search Here...">
            <span class="input-group-btn">
       <button type ="submit" id="searchbtn"class="btn btn-default">Search</button>
      </span>
          </div>
        </form>
      </div>
      <div class="navbar-right form-inline">
        <div class=" collapse navbar-collapse navbar-form" id="navForm">
          <!--<div>-->
          <button id="signupbtn" type="button" class="btn dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Sign Up</button>
          <div class="dropdown-menu">
            <div class="text-center">
              <h4><b> Sign Up</b></h4>
            </div>
            <br>
            <form autocomplete="off">
              <div class="form-group">
                <label for="firstname">Firstname</label>
                <input type="text" id="firstname" tabindex="1" class="form-control" placeholder="Firstname">
              </div>
              <div class="form-group">
                <label for="lastname">Lastname</label>
                <input type="text" id="lastname" tabindex="2" class="form-control" placeholder="Lastname">
              </div>
              <div class="form-group">
                <label for="username">Username</label>
                <input type="text" tabindex="3" class="form-control" placeholder="Username">
              </div>
              <div class="form-group">
                <label for="email">Email</label>
                <input type="email" tabindex="4" class="form-control" placeholder="Email">
              </div>
            </form>
          </div>
          <!--</div>-->
          <!--<div>-->
          <button id="loginbtn" type="button" class="btn dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false"> Sign In</button>
          <div class="dropdown-menu">
            <div class="text-center">
              <h4><b> Sign In</b></h4>
            </div>
            <br>
            <form autocomplete="off">
              <div class="form group">
                <label for="username">Username</label>
                <input type="text" id="username" tabindex="1" class="form-control" placeholder="Username" autocomplete="off">
              </div>
              <div class="form-group">
                <label for="password">Password</label>
                <input type="password" id="password" tabindex="2" class="form-control" placeholder="Password" autocomplete="off">
              </div>
              <br>
              <div class="form-group">
                <div class="text-center">
                  <a href="#" class="forgot-password">Forgot password?</a>
                </div>
              </div>
              <br>
              <br>
              <div>
                <button id="submitbtn" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-block">Sign In</button>
              </div>
            </form>
          </div>
          <!--</div>-->
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </nav>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Yes when I add the btn group class it looks good on desktop but it doesn't display right on mobile